# Ask for a cron expression

Tags: cron

I need to write a cron expression as follows, Could some one help write it for me?Thanks

```
7:30 am, day 1-7(1st day-7th day in month), every month
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: If you want to build up a cron-expression, have a look at https://crontab.guru/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By referring to this format

```
<second> <minute> <hour> <day-of-month> <month> <day-of-week> <year> <command>
```

The cron expression should be `0 30 7 1-7 * ?`

Comment: Thanks @john-joe. That's excellent answer and explanation, thanks!

Comment: just want to add that i personally like to go [here](https://crontab.guru/#0_0,12_1_*/2_*) to test out my cron expressions.